# How to create User Account Registration form with Webform?

Tags: webforms, users

I am using Drupal 7. I have Webform with 6 fields:

- Your name
- User name
- password
- Email
- phone number
- Website

If we submit it will store in database, but here I need username & password should store in "User Account Registration" form also.

We can add fields from Configuration -> People -> Account settings for other fields, but it doesn't work in this situation. I need to store the User name & password values to "User Account Form" and then to login with that username and password.

Comment: what is the reason for not using the profile fields instead of webform?

Answer (score 3):

Storing the password as a regular Webform field is not nearly as secure as using Drupal's built-in user registration password. I would recommend instead of trying to create user registration via Webform, that you use something like [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) to add additional information fields to the core registration form.

Comment: Is there no way to change the <input type = "password"... for password field?. if no.. I'll prefer for using "Profile2", but after submitting the form, I need sending an Email of all field values. Is it possible in Profile2? In webform we have settings for sending Email. Please suggest me .. how to do this task?

Comment: I found the working functionality of above task from this Link - http://drupal.org/node/1336486 [Useful posts -> #5 or #6].

Comment: Changing the input type of the HTML form element will cause it to display dots or stars rather than the characters being typed, but it won't affect the way Drupal stores the input in the database. The password field is stored (I believe) as a salted hash rather than as plaintext.

Comment: E-mailing passwords in plaintext is very bad security practice. A one-time token-protected link that allows the user to reset their password is preferred.